# How to find and kill specific Monitoring AGENT running on system?

Tags: networking, server, python, process, background-process

I have an agent installed on my computer which works with `python`. I think it starts with `startup` but I could not find any program on startup so I decided to check running processes for python and to my surprise, there was the agent `keep_alive()`

```
(base) admin1@shady-pc:~$ ps -fA | grep python
root      6533     1  0 10:27 ?        00:00:01 python /opt/SapphireIMSAgent/SapphireIMS.pyc keep_alive
```

So if it is `keep_alive`, it must be listening to a port so I checked the ports and found

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for admin1: 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6533/python
```

Killing the process `6533` kills the process **for some time only and it starts again**. I checked the **hidden startup processes** but could not find anything. Also, I looked at the `system monitor` and there was no process `6533`.

Obviously it must be running in the background so **How can I find and Kill the origin of this agent after each startup**?